# sql group by with group condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a product table Like:

```
id    p_name      s_date
1     A               2014-10-10
2     B               2014-10-02
3     A               2014-10-08
4     A               2014-10-11
5     B               2014-10-08
```

I need to group on p_name. query like

```
SELECT * FROM product GROUP BY p_name;
```

This query retrieving record 1 and 2. But I need to check `p_date` with current date when grouping on `p_name`. If current date is '2014-10-11' I need record 4 for product group 'A'  because record 4 matched with current date and record 2 for product group 'B' because no one of p_name 'B'  matched with current date. A query to check `p_date` with current date when grouping on `p_name`. i need to retrieve the record from group which matched with current date, if no record matched with current date then the record of minimum date.

Comment: i think what you want is if statement in mysql ..

Comment: yes. Like if statement.

Comment: Fot group `B` why the record 2 selected not the other one? what is the rule in that case? the minimum date or what??

Comment: if there are no future records you can do Max(p_date)

Comment: for group B record 2 selected because of minimum date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can have a check with the MySQL [Having](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx) clause.. and modify the query to somewhat like...

```
SELECT * FROM product GROUP BY p_name HAVING p_date = CURDATE();
```

Comment: if any group do not match with current date then that group data will not retrieved.

Comment: i need to retrieve the record from group which matched with current date, if no record matched with current date then the record of minimum date.

Comment: Well in that case then you would need to write 2 queries... one for checking with CURDATE()... and if this returns no data then another query for min date...